# Error in foreign key association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :reports, :foreign_key => "assigned_user_id"
  ...
end
```

**report.rb**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assigned_user, :class_name => "User"
end
```

**index action**

```
def index
  @all_reports = Report.all
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @all_reports.each do |report| %>
  <%= report.user.email %> </br>
<% end %>
```

This throws me the error:

```
undefined method `user' for #<Report:0x007f90dc642e80>
```

What am I missing? My other - standard rails - associations work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<%= report.user.email %> </br>
```

To:

```
<%= report.assigned_user.email %> </br>
```